# Publish git subtree to subfolder of different git repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a project `suman-types`

I want to publish a git subtree of the `suman-types` Git repo to `DefinitelyTyped/types/suman`.

Normally with a Git subtree, you publish a subtree of a Git project as the root of another Git project. But in this case I am wondering if I can publish a git subtree of a project (suman-types) to a subfolder of existing Git repo (my fork of DefinitelyTyped here:

https://github.com/ORESoftware-team/DefinitelyTyped

so what I want to do is something like this:

```
cd suman-types && 
git subtree push --prefix types my-remote master/types
```

where master/types is a subdirectory in the master branch. I don't think this is the right syntax, but hopefully you get the idea.

*Perhaps I need to use git submodules instead of git subtree.*